# Simple awk scripts that takes no arguments or input file

Tags: linux, shell, awk, terminal

I am trying to write a simple awk script that doesn't use any file input arguments or anything. I only tested it writing a hello world program so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk
BEGIN{}
{print "hello"}
END{}
```

I get an error `awk: 1: unexpected character '.'` when I try to run it through terminal using: `./program.awk`
Why is this happening?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `-f` to end of shebang line like this to tell `awk` that the script follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
```

Also, as you have no input, put the `print` inside `BEGIN`block:

```
BEGIN {print "Hi"}
```

Comment: so if I understand you correctly -f flag tells awk to run `./program.awk` script and `BEGIN {}` block is used to do stuff that don't need input file? so main block `{...}` uses input file to operate on?

Comment: Nearly - when you run `./program.awk` a new process is created and it executes `awk` in that process and the `-f` tells `awk` that the script follows in this file. The stuff in `BEGIN{}` gets executed before any input is read which is ideal for your use case without any input data. The stuff in subsequent `{...}` gets executed for each subsequent line of input, but you have no input, so it will probably hang waiting.

Comment: Does `END{...}` block also hang in case I have no input files, even if I dont create main block in my script?

Comment: Probably - I am not sure of the actual logic and I wouldn't be surprised if the flavours of `awk` differ. Note that you can always use `/dev/null` as an *empty* input file and `yes` as an endless input file.

Comment: Thank you very much, that was explained very well :)

Comment: No, an `END` block never hangs. In old, broken awk a BEGIN block with no input and no explicit `exit` statement would hang but that's a different situation. My advice - never call awk via a shebang as it robs you of the ability to separate shell command arguments into awk arguments and variables and/or execute shell functionality (getopts?) around the awk script. Just call awk explicitly from the shell script.